# Java: Modifying an object (declared in Class A, instanced in Class B) in Class C

Tags: java, class, object, interface

I am coding a little game and part of the game is to add a shop interface to an already existing pet interface.
I have chosen a Cat. The Cat class holds the Cat object constructor.

```
    public Cat(String aName, Gender aGender ,String aTrait,String aAgeEffect,int aWeight, int aPetDay, int aPetMonth, int aPetYear, String aWhiskerLength, String aFurColour, String aEyeColour){   
    super(aName, aGender , aTrait,  aWeight,  aAgeEffect, aPetDay, aPetMonth, aPetYear);
    petDay = aPetDay;
    petMonth = aPetMonth;
    petYear = aPetYear;
    whiskerLength = aWhiskerLength;
    furColour = aFurColour;
    eyeColour = aEyeColour;
    penaltyPoints = 0;
        }
```

Then, the Cat_Interface class sets up an instance of the Cat using user input.

```
public Cat_Interface() {
        final Cat cat = new Cat(name, null, trait, null, 50, day, month, year, null, fur, eye);
}
```

(The name, etc variables are temporary ones I use to pass through user inputs. The Cat object does work. I have tested it many times and all values are passed through correctly.)

My problems are beginning to arise now when I create the PetShopInterface class + try and use the object that is created in the Cat_Interface class ( cat ).

I try this, as an example, when I have the interface for the shop set up:

```
public void buyBed() {
System.out.println(Cat_Interface.cat.getName());
}
```

Just to see what will happen. I get a null pointer pointing at this piece of code.
This shouldn't be happening as I'm running the Cat_Interface class first, setting up a new Cat and then launching the shop interface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you post in SO, try to make your formatting better. Specifically, 4 spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: All you need is a reference to an object, in order to modify it (if it's mutable).  But you can't do it without that reference.  And simply having a reference variable that has the same class type is not like having the actual reference.

Comment: BTW, you should not use "Interface" as a part of your class names.  "Interface" has a distinct meaning in Java (and this ain't it).

Comment: We have been told for this game that we have to call the classes Cat, Cat_Interface etc. I know it's bad practice but I'm just doing what I'm told :)

By "reference" do you mean something like:
public Cat_Interface myInterface;
In the other class?

Comment: By "reference" I mean a *value* stored in something like `Cat_inteface myInterface` that *actually addresses* the object you want to operate on (and not NULL and not some other instance of Cat_Interface).  Simply having a variable of the type is not having the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cat_Interface() {
    final Cat cat = new Cat(...);
}
```

This creates a new cat within the scope of the constructor. You want something like this:

```
public final Cat cat;

public Cat_Interface() {
    cat = new Cat(...);
}
```

And then you need to instantiate it:

```
Cat_Interface ci = new CatInterface();
System.out.println(ci.cat.getName());
```

Comment: I have made the changes as you said. However, the instance of the Cat_Interface has been declared in another class (the tester)

I can't refer to that instance of the interface in the PetShopInterface class without still doing Cat_Interface.cat.getname()

Comment: Is it supposed to be static?